# Getting full seconds and microseconds from Numpy datetime64

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, timedelta, datetime64

I need to get a timedelta as a full float of seconds and microseconds, for instance 2.786 seconds. Doing this with datetime64's specifying 'ms' as milliseconds

```
elapsed_time = np.datetime64(dial_1, 'ms') - np.datetime64(dial_2, 'ms')
```

Gives me `numpy.timedelta64(-2786,'ms')` Great, but I need that in seconds. Doing that now by specifying seconds

```
elapsed_time = np.datetime64(dial_1, 's') - np.datetime64(dial_2, 's')
```

Now gives `numpy.timedelta64(-3,'s')` and has rounded it upto a whole 3 seconds. I just want to know how to get the decimal 2.786 seconds

Any help much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

IIUC divide difference by 1 second:

```
dial_1 = 0
dial_2 = 2786
elapsed_time = (np.datetime64(dial_1, 'ms') - np.datetime64(dial_2, 'ms')) / np.timedelta64(1, 's')
print (elapsed_time)
-2.786
```

Answer (score 0):

### Relation in `second` & `milisecond`

> 1. `1 second` = `1000 milisecond`    and      `1 milisecond` = `1/1000 second`
> 2. `2.786 second` = `2786 milisecond`

If we take 2 dials i.e `dial_1=0 milisecond` and `dial_2=2786 milisecond`, then

#### output in milisecond-->

```
import numpy as np

dial_1 = 0
dial_2 = 2786
elapsed_time = np.datetime64(dial_1, 'ms') - np.datetime64(dial_2, 'ms')
print(elapsed_time)

OUTPUT:
    -2786 milliseconds
```

> if we need output in `float` then we `can't assign float value i.e dial_2=2.786`
> because `np.datetime64(2.786, 's')` give error i.e `ValueError: Could not convert object to NumPy datetime`

if we need output in `float` then use `timedelta64`

> timedelta64 are a number, to represent the number of units, and a date/time unit, such as (D)ay, (M)onth, (Y)ear, (h)ours, (m)inutes, or (s)econd

> `dial = 1000 milisecond` = `dial = 1 second`

#### output in second-->

```
import numpy as np

dial_1 = 0
dial_2 = 2786
dial = 1000
elapsed_time = (np.datetime64(dial_1, 's') - np.datetime64(dial_2, 's'))/(np.timedelta64(dial, 's'))
print(elapsed_time)

OUTPUT:
    -2.786
```